# Visual Studio doesn't have required files to program with Windows Phone

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone

I tried installing "Windows Mobile Station 6 Standard SDK" on my computer so that I could program for my phone with Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2010. After three hours of installing all the minor updates for Visual Studio, I still found that this error occurred.

After trying twice, this window popped up immediately on hitting the next button on the installer for *WMS 6 Standard SDK* telling me that I needed Windows Visual Studio 2005 or later, which I do. How do I get the SDK installed so that I can program to my phone? I don't know how to install *Windows Mobile Device Center* because the link on the official Microsoft Tutorial for programming on my phone goes to *windowsphone.com*.

**Other Info:**
I have Windows Vista, a Windows 8 Phone, Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional Version, and I am running on Intel Centrino

**EDIT:** I just tried installing *Mobile Device Center Driver* Update and it said "This installation package is not supported by this processor type. Contact your product vendor." Does this mean I just can't do this with an Intel Processor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the Windows Phone SDK, not Windows Mobile, which is a legacy platform.

- WP8 SDK - https://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/downloadsdk (requires Win 8 AND VS2012)
- WP7 SDK - http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27570

Comment: WP7 Doesn't support my graphics chip I don't think and WP8 is for Windows 8, so I can't use it.

Comment: Windows Phone and Windows Mobile are completely different platforms. You can't produce an app for your Windows Phone 8 with the Windows Mobile SDK. Furthermore, Windows Mobile is a dead platform. There are no devices that use it any more, unless you have an old Windows Mobile phone.

Comment: ^ Then how do I program an app for my Windows 8 phone without the SDK?

Comment: You don't. You need either the WP7 or WP8 SDK. I would look into a new machine if you are not meeting the minimum requirements for either of these SDKs.

Comment: OK. This would be a correct answer then. I am looking into a new computer anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Added to the above answers, after installation of WP8 SDK in Windows 8 system which has 64 bit and Hyper V available.

There are few steps to be followed to make an app to your WP8

1. Developer account has to be created, which costs you.
2. Have to unlock your phone.(this method is followed just to install untrusted XAP)
3. Develop your required app.
4. Get installed in your WP8.